# LuaInterface in C#

Tags: c#, lua, using, visual-c#-express-2010, luainterface

I am a complete "noob" to C#, however I do know some C, although that is a good start, it's not enough. I have downloaded the most recent version of LuaInterface, and the download in cluded two files: lua51.dll, and LuaInterface.dll. I cannot figure out how to use this in my C# project, and be able to run Lua within it. If anyone can help, it would be great. Please don't use a very complicated explanation if you can. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click on the project and select add reference.  Then select the browse tab and select the dll's from their respective directories.

Comment: Note: this is if you are using Visual Studio for the project

Comment: What would I do if I was using Visual C#? Or are they the same thing?

Comment: @SamH: Yes, they are the same thing. VC# is part of Visual Studio.

Comment: haha, I'm glad to help; I had the same problem when I first started :p

Comment: I'm trying to learn C# so I can make games for the Xbox 360. I'm pretty far from that, though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add references to the dlls. Note I had trouble getting the lua interface working for .net 4.0 and x64 machines. I had to download the source and recompile it myself. You can find the source here: http://www.lua.org/ftp/